# Alternative theming for subdomain

Tags: theming, 8, subsites

I would like a different set of twig templates be used for all content that exists on a sub-domain of a website regardless of content type.

eg:

- mysite.com/article (Main site theme)
- sub.mysite.com/article (New templates)

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the domain to the template names in a theme name suggestion hook for each template, but if you want to have a complete set of twig templates for each domain it might be easier to create separate themes and switch them. In custom code with a theme negotiator or with this module [Domain Theme Switch](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_theme_switch).